# Start a Simple Animation

Tags: android, animation

As part of a much more complex piece of functionality I've become stuck on the ability to show a circle becoming opaque at a certain point of the screen.

I've gone as far as to create a test project where my Animation code is as follows:

```
View mLongPressImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mLongPressImage = findViewById(R.id.onPressImage);

     findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAnimation(v.getX(), v.getY());
            }
        });
}

private AlphaAnimation onPressAnimation;

private void startAnimation(final float f, final float g) {
    Log.v("", "START");
    mLongPressImage.setX(f);
    mLongPressImage.setY(g);
    onPressAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
    onPressAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    onPressAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    onPressAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
    mLongPressImage.startAnimation(onPressAnimation);
}
```

Logging show's the correct event's are happening.

View looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="PRESS ME" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/onPressImage"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_circle_onpress" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Right now the Image simply appears at the coordinates after 1 second has passed.

Can anybody point out the hidden flaw in this extremely simple piece of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code seems to be technically correct which is why I was having such a big problem solving it.

The issue was caused by me using `setX()` and `setY()` and `Animation` together - On my Xoom tablet (running 3.2 API 13) this caused some pretty funky behaviour even after switching to `ScaleAnimation`.

Removing the `setX()` and `setY()` removes the glitchy behaviour as does switching to a Galaxy Nexus (Running API 4.0 Icecream Sandwich). Setting `hardwareAccelerated` to `true` instead of removing the `setX()` and `setY()` also improved the problem (but didn't fix it completely).

If anyone know's **why** this is I'll be more than happy to upvote and change the accepted answer on this one. I'm going to chalk it up to a flakey Android API until then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsatisfied with black background around circle, you can change `ImageView` background to following (notice two addtional zeros to describe alpha channel value):

`android:background="#00000000"`